# How do i calculate $Cov(X,Z)$, for $Z=X+Y$?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X,Y$ be independent random variables which are poisson distributed with the parameters $\lambda > 0$ and $2\lambda$.

Let $Z := X+Y$.

1. Calculate $P[Z=0]$
2. Calculate $Cov(X,Z)$

**Task 1.:**

I know that $Z=X+Y$ is again poisson distributed such that $Z\sim Poi(\lambda + 2\lambda)$.
So it follows that $$P(Z=0) = \frac{3\lambda^0}{0!}e^{-3\lambda} = 3e^{-3\lambda}$$.

**Task 2:**

$$Cov(X,Z) = E[XZ]-E[X]E[Z] $$

How do i calculate $E[XZ]$?

Is it allowed to do the following:
$$E[XZ] = E[X(X+Y)]=E[X^2 + XY] =E[X^2]+E[XY] = E[X^2]+E[X]E[Y]$$

kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that $X$ and $Y$ take values in $\mathbb{N}$, we have:

$$ \lbrace Z = 0 \rbrace = \lbrace X = 0 \; \text{and} \; Y = 0 \rbrace. $$

Because $X$ and $Y$ are independent,

$$ \mathbb{P}\big( \lbrace X = 0 \; \text{and} \; Y = 0 \rbrace \big) = \mathbb{P}(X = 0) \mathbb{P}(Y = 0). $$

Covariance is bilinear. Therefore:

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Cov}(X, Z) & = {} \mathrm{Cov}(X, X+Y) \\[2mm]
 & = \mathrm{Cov}(X, X) + \mathrm{Cov}(X,Y).
\end{align*}
$$

Because $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) = 0$. [Note that the converse is not true ! Having $\mathrm{Cov}(X, Y) = 0$ does not necessarily imply that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.]

As a result:

$$ \mathrm{Cov}(X, Z) = \mathrm{Cov}(X, X) = \mathrm{Var}(X). $$

Since $X \sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda)$, $\mathrm{Var}(X) = \lambda$.

Comment: You are my hero. Does the same hold for $Z=Y-X$?

Comment: You mean $\mathbb{P}(Z = 0)$ if $Z = Y - X$ ? No because $X = 0$ and $Y = 0$ is not the only possibility. Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $Y - X \sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda)$. Then, $\mathbb{P}(Z = 0) = e^{-\lambda}.$ However, if you want to find this result from scratch, note that:
$$ \lbrace Z = 0 \rbrace = \bigcup \limits_{l=0}^{+\infty} \lbrace X = l, \, Y = l \rbrace. $$

Comment: My question was related to the covariance $Cov(X,Y-X)$, can I write it as $$Cov(X,Y-X) = Cov(X,Y) - Cov(X,X)$$ ^^?

Comment: Yes, this equality is true.

Comment: Alright, now I understood it i think. thanks. You are awesome and saved my live (tomorrow is my exam) :)